# Preventing JList from auto resizing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist, preferredsize

I have a JList inside a JScrollPane that's placed in a JPanel (BorderLayout.CENTER) and putting that inside another JPanel's BorderLayout.EAST (this JPanel's CENTER contains another JPanel) and this whole JPanel is placed inside a JTabbedPane. Initially, it would look like this: 
[image: Initial JList GUI]

Now I add some books to the list:

[image: JList with some books in it]

If I go to another tab and come back, this happens:

[image: Resized JList]

What I don't understand is that, the JPanel containing the JList has both its minimum and maximum size set:

```
JPanel listPanel = new JPanel();
listPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
listPanel.add(new JScrollPane(bookList), BorderLayout.CENTER);
listPanel.setMinimumSize(listPanel.getPreferredSize());
listPanel.setMaximumSize(listPanel.getPreferredSize());
checkOutPanel.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

How can I prevent the JList from auto resizing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on what it is you trying archive, you can either use [`JList#setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28E%29) or [`JList#setFixedCellWidth`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setFixedCellWidth%28int%29). These will feed back into the PeferredScrollableViewportSize method which will effect the scroll pane

Comment: Thank you, the setPrototypeCellValue is quite useful!